# This code do not compile, this is figure environments inside tabular environment, adding captions and labels

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats, tabularx

This code do not compile, this is figure environments inside tabular environmet, adding captions and labels.

I havent found the reason and an effective way to organize my graphs. This is the code Im using.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,draft]{beamer}



\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{Implementación del Metodo de diferencias en redes cristlinas}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{RepRedSC2D}
\caption{Replicación de celdas Unitarias}
\label{redes}
\end{figure}        
s&  s  \\
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.156]{11UnitSC2D}
\caption{Celda Unitaria SC -2D}
\label{Unit2D}
\end{figure}   \\
    s   &   d   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are nesting environments in a non allowed way. How exactly are you trying to present the information?

Comment: Changing the `tabular` format specification to use `p{...}` columns, as in `\begin{tabular}{p{.45\textwidth}p{.45\textwidth}}` will give you compilable code, but it seems that you are doing too much unnecessary nesting. What exactly do you want?

Comment: You mustn't nest a `figure` environment inside a `table` environment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Im trying to make a flux diagram, explaning a procces, my general sketch was to get the images like in the vertices of a square distribution and conect the images with arrows in somehow way, that is why I thought about nesting in tabular environment.

Comment: So, you have four images, each with its caption and you want to show them in a 2x2 array, drawing some arrows from some images to others. Is that correct?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina And using some arrows to represent the flux, that is correct.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Please see my updated answer. Is something like that what you have in mind?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It is exactly what I had in mind thanks, but this diagrams have so many code that Im taking seriusly the search of a tool that generates the code of diagrams created in graph interfaces. Doing this manually is very exaustive for just iniciated people in latex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use `c` for the columns and this specifier doesn't admit paragraph-like material; changing to `p{...}` columns solves the problem. However, looking at the nesting in your code, it seems that you are using unnecessary nesting levels.

According to comments to the question, you want to organize some images in a 2x2 array. Each figure should have its own caption; additionally, you want to draw arrows between some of the figures. In this case, you can use the following approach:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Implementación del Metodo de diferencias en redes cristlinas}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}
  }
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen11)   
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}};
  \caption{Replicación de celdas Unitarias}
  \label{redes}
  & 
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen12)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}};
  \caption{Replicación de otras celdas}
  \label{redesi}
  \\
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen21)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-c}};
  \caption{Celda Unitaria SC -2D}
  \label{Unit2D}
  & 
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen22)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}};
  \caption{Otra Celda Unitaria}
  \label{Unit2Di}
 \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,overlay,
  >=latex,
  shorten >= 10pt,
  shorten <= 10pt,
  magenta
]
\draw[->]
  (imagen11) -- (imagen12);
\draw[->,shorten <= 30pt]
  (imagen12) -- (imagen22);
\draw[->]
  (imagen22) -- (imagen21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The idea is to use a `tabular` for the images; each cell will have an image placed inside a TikZ `\node`. The `remember picture` key is used, so then you can use the names provided for the `\node`s to draw the desired arrows.